# Question about an Euclidean Domain (associates)

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-domain

I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ED with an euclidean function $\varphi\left(x\right)=\left|x\right| $. But in [Euclidean Domain, Associates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814236/euclidean-domain-associates) they say that ED iff Field. Isn't it contradictory? Is the asker wrong?

Comment: Indeed, *too* fast. It is not clear what you are asking.  What are you trying to prove that needs every element invertible?

Comment: I find it a contradiction $\mathbb{Z}$ can be a ED and ED iff Field, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field.

Comment: Only need  the unit $u$ in $a=bu$ to be invertible (a unit) for $a,b$ to be associates.

Comment: Why do you believe that an ED must be a field?

Comment: Okay I will change my question in order to be clear.

Comment: Hope you can understand me now

Comment: You are correct:  not all Euclidean domains are fields.  Both $\mathbb Z$ and $K[x]$ ($K$ a field) are counterexamples.

Comment: Thank you so much @RaviFernando !!